# CSS3 equivalent to width:calc(100% - 10px)

Tags: css, webkit, qtwebkit

I'm searching for an alternative to migrate my CSS - already working on FF and Chrome -, because QtWebKit it's not rendering some CSS3 feature yeat.

I have the following stuff:

```
.fit {
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 10px);
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 10px);
    width: -o-calc(100% - 10px);
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
}
```

I want a class to fit all element as displayed in wireframe example.

[image]

**Note:** Almost all CSS3 features can be perfect rendered, but as sayed before `*-calc()` have issues and can't find other solution eg. using `margin-right`, `padding-right` etc.

**@EDIT:** I created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dj3hh/ to show the expected behavior - You can resize fiddle and all margins respect `10px` from right. I want a new way to do this withou `calc()`

Comment: With Qt-Webkit CSS `calc`

Comment: Would it be possible to make a simplified example in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: 1. please provide a jsfiddle 2. jQuery allowed?

Comment: perhaps an approximation would be okay with `width:90%` or something similar? If you need to abide by the exact `10px` you could introduce a wrapper element.

Comment: @BramVanroy I edited and put the fiddle - see the example.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you change the box model rendering to `box-sizing: borderbox` then the padding will be included in the total width instead of being added to it. 
With this example I am assuming you are adding the class to the wrapping elements.

```
.fit { 
    width:100%
    padding-right:10px
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;     
    box-sizing: border-box; 

}
```

Browser support is very good; all modern browsers. Only you will need a polyfill for IE7 and under.

For more background info: paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

---

EDIT:

This is a solution that I believe completely meets your brief, please see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/David_Knowles/UUPF2/

```
.fit { 
    width:100%
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;     
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}

td {
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: padding !== margin ! Your solution is different to what the OP wants.

Comment: @timidfriendly Compare both (with calc) http://jsfiddle.net/dj3hh/ (with box-sizing) http://jsfiddle.net/dj3hh/1/

Comment: For completeness; removing the padding-right from .fit and apply it to the <td> is I believe exactly what you were looking for.

Comment: I highly recommend * { box-sizing: border-box; } for all new projects.  I assume most people don't have to support IE7?

Answer (score 1):

Put `position: relative` on the parent element, then do...

```
.fit {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 10px;
}
```